# How can I insert an applet in my HTML

Tags: java, applet

I have a Applet that extends from JApplet and 5 another classes that interact with this JApplet one, but I need to put this applet in my HTML page.

How can I do that ?

I Try the follow code

```
<applet archive="test.jar"
    width="100" height="100">
</applet>
```

both files (HTML and JAR) are in the sme directory, but nothing happens...no errors....but my applet don't loaded.

I read something about Manifest but I can't put it because I extend from JApplet

**EDITED: Code**
My main class called FormMain

```
public FormMain() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Initialize GUI.
 */
public void init() {

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    this.setSize(515, 560);

    this.setContentPane(createContentPane());

    this.fingerprintSDKSample = new Util(this);
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) An applet does not really need a constructor. 3) Calling `setSize(515, 560);` is wrong in most cases, but especially for an applet whose size is set in HTML.  If you want to set the size at run-time, use a `JFrame` and JWS. 4) A manifest can specify a 'main' class for an applet.  Java 5+(?) JREs will check the manifest.  But specify it in the `code` attribute for more reliable deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CODE**, **WIDTH**, and **HEIGHT** are mandatory attributes for an applet tag. You have not defined the Code attribute.

If your `start()` section is in a file called `someclass.class`, you need to specify the code parameter in your applet tag as follows:

```
<applet archive="test.jar"
    width="100" height="100" code="someclass.class">
</applet>
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#applet)

Comment: The class you specified, is it present in your java archive? You must specify the full qualified name `x.y.z.mainclass.class`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. I rread a tutorial, how to create a Jar file and I just follow it and associate in my <APPLET> tag

Comment: Which is the main class of your applet? The one that contains `start()`. You should specify that class in the code parameter.

Comment: My main class called FormMain, and has a init(). When I specify in the code parameter this class, show me an error "ClassNotFound"

Comment: Open your jar archive. Is FormMain.class present within some folder in it?

Comment: I found 2 files, a .project and a .classpath

Comment: What about folders? Did you find any?

Comment: I click in Export -> JAR FILE -> NEXT -> NEXT -> FINISH

Comment: Upload your jar file. I think there might be something wrong with it.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a new .Jar file, but I got some errors. Resource is out of sync with the File Syste: .project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13941/discussion-between-darkxphenomenon-and-lucas-santos)